# Transitive models and reflection of $\Sigma_n$ fragments of $\sf ZF.$

Tags: set-theory

For each $n\in \mathbb N,$ let $\sf ZF_n$ be the theory $\sf ZF$, only with $\Sigma_n$-replacement instead of full replacement. There is a well-known theorem

> **Theorem 1.** For any $n,$ $\sf ZF$ proves that there is a transitive model of $\sf ZF_n.$

I've never seen a detailed proof of this given and I've always been under the impression that it was a straightforward consequence of the reflection theorem

> **Theorem 2** For any $n$, $\sf ZF$ proves that for any ordinal $\alpha,$ there is an ordinal $\beta > \alpha$ such that for any $\Sigma_n$ formula $\varphi(\vec x )$ and any $\vec x\in V_\beta,$ $\models_n\varphi(\vec x)$ if and only if $V_\beta \models \varphi(\vec x)$

where $\models_n$ is the $\Sigma_n$ truth predicate.

I don't believe I've ever seen a proof of this either, but I don't have any difficulty adopting the proof of the version of the reflection theorem I have seen, that works for any finite number of formulas rather than for an entire $\Sigma_n$ classes, using the $\Sigma_n$ truth predicate.

But on closer examination, I can't quite clinch how we prove Theorem 1 from Theorem 2?

It would follow if we could prove

> **Lemma** For any $n$ $\sf ZF$ proves that for every $\Sigma_n$ replacement instance $\varphi,$ $\models_n\varphi$.

the key point being that the quantification over formulas occurs inside $\sf ZF.$

The reason this isn't a difficult leap to make in the version with a finite number of formulas is since we can show an (externally) finite set of $\sf ZF$ axioms hold one by one. So, it occurs to me that this whole thing would be a non-issue if we could show that for each $n$, $\sf ZF_n$ is finitely axiomatizable. This seems plausible (even likely given that the analogous fragments of $\sf PA$ are finitely axiomatizable), though on the other hand the lemma above seems like a natural route to proving this since I would guess the theorem it asserts is provable axiomatizes $\Sigma_n$-replacement.

So my questions are:

1. Is $\sf ZF_n$ finitely axiomatizable, and if so, what's the simplest proof?
2. More generally, how do we prove Theorem 1 (as a simple consequence of Theorem 2, or otherwise)?

Comment: You should restrict Separation also to $\Sigma_n$-formulas, or it is hard to say the resulting theory is finitely axiomatizable. Mathias proved that $\mathsf{Z}$, Zermelo set theory (without Replacement) is not finitely axiomatizable, and I would be surprised if adding the $\Sigma_1$-Replacement makes the whole theory finitely axiomatizable.

Comment: @HanulJeon Yes, good point, I haven’t thought over the complexities there. Let’s say for definiteness we’re using an axiomatization of ZF that doesn’t have separation axioms at all, only replacement, which I think is essentially the same effect as your suggestion. (On a side note, I think that goes back much further than Mathias.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $\mathsf{ZF}_n$ means the theory obtained from $\mathsf{ZF}$ by restricting Separation and **Collection** to $\Sigma_n$-formulas. You may replace Collection to Replacement when $n\ge 2$, but I am not sure what happens when $n=1$.

---

You can see that $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves not only we can define the $\Sigma_n$-truth predicate but also it is actually $\Sigma_n$-definable for $n \ge 1$. You may find its proof from Jech's book as exercises.

From this, we can prove Theorem 1: By the reflection principle, we can find $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha$ reflects $\models_{\Sigma_n}$, that is, for $a\in V_\alpha$ and a (code for a) $\Sigma_n$-formula $\phi$,
$$\vDash_n\phi(a) \iff V_\alpha\models (\vDash_n\phi(a)).$$
But you can see that $V_\alpha\models (\vDash_n\phi(a))$ if and only if $V_\alpha\models \phi(a)$, which means $V_\alpha\prec_{\Sigma_n} V$.

Then let us check the complexity of $\Sigma_n$-replacement, and you can see that an instance of $\Sigma_n$-Collection
$$\forall x\in a\exists y\phi(x,y)\to \exists b\forall x\in a\exists y\in b\phi(x,y)$$
with a parameter $a$ is a $\Pi_n\lor\Sigma_n$-statement. It means if $V_\alpha\prec_{\Sigma_n} V$, then $V_\alpha$ satisfies $\mathsf{ZF}_n$.

---

Answering your first question requires further analysis on $\models_{\Sigma_n}$. We can state the definition of $\models_{\Sigma_n}$ over $\mathsf{ZF}_n$, and it works perfectly, then we can state $\Sigma_n$-Collection and $\Sigma_n$-Separation as single sentences. However, we are not sure whether the definition of $\models_{\Sigma_n}$ really gives a $\Sigma_n$-truth predicate if we work with a restricted Replacement to $\Sigma_n$-formulas.

Well, it is a bit incorrect to say $\models_{\Sigma_n}$ does not work if we follow Jech's definition. For $n\ge 1$, $\mathsf{ZF}_n$ proves every set has a transitive closure. This shows $\models_{\Sigma_0}$ is definable. Jech defined $\models_{\Sigma_n}$ inductively by letting $\models_{\Sigma_{k+1}}(\exists x\phi)[a_0,\cdots,a_k]$ iff $\phi$ is $\Pi_n$ and
$$\exists a\not\vDash_{\Sigma_k} \lnot\phi[a,a_0,\cdots,a_k].$$
The problem is that Jech defined the $\Sigma_n$-truth predicate to a restricted form of formulas, that is, formulas of the form
$$\exists x_0\forall x_1\cdots \mathsf{Q} x_n \phi(x_0,\cdots,x_n,\vec{y})$$
for a bounded $\phi$. ($\mathsf{Q}$ is a quantifier that depends on the parity of $n$.) We do not know if we can reduce formulas to the above form in general, which I will call *reduced $\Sigma_n$-formulas.*

Fortunately, we can see that $\mathsf{ZF}_n$ proves reduced $\Sigma_n$ formulas are "closed under" disjunctions, conjunctions, bounded quantifiers, and unbounded $\exists$ in the following sense:

> **Main Lemma.** Let $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(y)$ be reduced $\Sigma_n$-formulas. Then $\mathsf{ZF}_n$ proves the following:
>
> 1. $\phi\land \psi$ and $\phi\lor\psi$ are equivalent to some reduced $\Sigma_n$-formula.
> 2. $\forall x\in a\phi(x)$ and $\exists x\in a\phi(x)$ is equivalent to a reduced $\Sigma_n$-formula.
> 3. $\exists x\phi(x)$ is equivalent to a reduced $\Sigma_n$-formula.

The proof for Main Lemma is, unfortunately, a bit long and tedious. Start the proof with induction on $n$, and you can see $\Sigma_n$-Collection allows you to 'remove' foremost bounded quantifiers. The case for disjunction and conjunction will follow if we know how to combine two unbounded existential quantifiers into a single one, so it boils down to the third case. The last one follows from the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** Bounded Zermelo set theory proves the following:
> Let $\phi(x_0,x_1,v_0,v_1,\cdots, v_{n-1})$ be a $\Delta_0$ formula. If we set
> \begin{equation*}
>     \psi(x,v_0,\cdots, v_{n-1})\equiv \exists u\in x\exists y_0\in u\exists y_1\in u [(x = \langle y_0,y_1\rangle) \land \phi(v_0,v_1,v_0,v_1,\cdots, v_{n-1})],
> \end{equation*}
> then $\psi$ is also $\Delta_0$ and we have
>
> 1. For any $x_0$ and $x_1$, if we let $x=\langle x_0,x_1\rangle$, then
>    \begin{equation*}
>            \forall v_0\forall v_1\cdots\forall v_{n-1}\ \phi(x_0,x_1,v_0,\cdots,v_{n-1})\leftrightarrow \psi(x,v_0,\cdots,v_{n-1}).
>        \end{equation*}
> 2. We have
>    \begin{equation*}
>            \forall x_0\forall x_1\exists v_0\forall v_1\cdots \mathsf{Q} v_{n-1} \phi(x_0,x_1,v_0,v_1,\cdots,v_{n-1}) \leftrightarrow \forall x\exists v_0\forall v_1\cdots \mathsf{Q} v_{n-1} \psi(x,v_0,v_1,\cdots,v_{n-1}).
>        \end{equation*}

Comment: The last paragraph of your second section is the whole thing I'm not getting. Why from 1) every $\Sigma_n$ instance of collection is $\Sigma_n\vee \Pi_n$, and 2) $V_\alpha\prec_{\Sigma_n} V,$ does it follow that $V_\alpha\models \sf ZF_n$? It seems obvious (which is why I've never thought twice about it all these years), but how do we prove $\models_n \sf ZF_n$? That's the purpose of the lemma I wrote down. (And sorry in advance if you've addressed this point and I missed it. I also haven't read through your last section yet.)

Comment: (Prove it without resorting to finite axiomatizability, that is.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I did not prove that $\models_n\mathsf{ZF}_n$, although we could do it. You can see that $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, so it satisfies Zermelo set theory, and it remains to show $V_\alpha$ satisfies $\Sigma_n$-Collection. But we see that $V_\alpha$ reflects each instance of $\Sigma_n$-Collection.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen The point of the latter part of my answer is a bit unclear even for me. Let me try to think about that point again. It is related to my current work in preparation, and one thing I can say is that the definition of $\Sigma_n$-formulas takes a significant role in this question, but set theorists do not care well about its definition quite well.

Comment: How could we do it (prove $\models_n \sf ZF_n$ )? I feel like it's something obvious I'm just missing, but I'd view an answer to that as an answer to the question. The rest of that part, i.e. that it follows that $V_\alpha\models \sf ZF_n,$ is clear.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen There are several issues we should discuss before talking about $\models_n\mathsf{ZF}_n$. The first problem is that $\models_n$ cannot handle formulas that are not $\Sigma_n$, that is, formulas in a prenex normal form starting with existential quantifiers and showing $n$ alternations of quantifiers. We know that every formula is equivalent to a prenex normal form, so we can "put" formulas whose prenex form is $\Sigma_n$ to $\models_n$. However, it does not guarantee the way we know how to compute the complexity works.

Comment: For example, without an appropriate form of Collection, there might be a chance that adding a bounded quantifier increases the complexity of a formula. The main lemma on my answer shows it does not happen if we have $\Sigma_n$-Collection.

Comment: The second issue is that axioms of $\mathsf{ZF}_n$ are more complex than $\models_n$ can take. An instance of $\Sigma_n$-Collection with a parameter $a$ for the domain is $\Sigma_n\lor\Pi_n$ (if we have $\Sigma_n$-Collection), and adding a universal quantifier to $a$ makes it $\Pi_{n+1}$. One possible way to avoid this issue is using a stronger truth predicate, like $\models_{n+1}$.

Comment: (Yes, I should acknowledge that $\models_n \mathsf{ZF}_n$ itself is nonsense by these two issues I mentioned. Despite that, the definability of $\models_n$ is sufficient to show the finite axiomatizability of $\mathsf{ZF}_n$, and we could still show $\models_m\mathsf{ZF}_n$ for a large $m$, possibly $m=n+1$.)

Comment: @HanulJeon Can you explain the equivalence "$V_\alpha\models (\vDash_n\phi(a))$ iff $V_\alpha\models \phi(a)$'' in detail please? I am confused about this: isn't $\vDash_n\phi(a) \leftrightarrow \phi(a)$ a scheme (where the second $\phi$ is the real formula)? If so, how can we make sure $V_\alpha$ reflect it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @user123 I mean $\vDash_n$ for a universal $\Sigma_n$-formula.